# Find specific values inside array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to insert conditioned values in an array into an empty array in exact position.

```
empty_array = np.zeros([40,100])
for x in range (1,24):
    array[x,:,:] #which is also sized 40x100
    if the_values_in_the_array < 0.25:
         the_values_in_the_array = 0
    empty_array = empty_array + array [x,:,:]
```

Which syntax should I use for this logic? And how should I scan the_values_in_the_array to find the conditioned values?

Comment: @F L, what is the dimension of your `array`, You said it is 40*100, why do you use `array[x,:,:]`, looks like it is 3-dimensional?

Comment: @MaThMaX yes, the x one is basically times. But the size is 40*100

Comment: It would be helpful to have the code reduced to a simple example that can run independently of outside definitions.  Here we have to assume what you mean by `array` and `the_values_in_the_array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
empty_array = np.zeros([40,100])
array = np.random.rand(24,40,100)

array[array<0.25]=0 # change all the values which is <0.25 to 0
for x in range(1,24):
    empty_array += array[x,:,:]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is much simpler than I thought it would be.

Comment: @FL, glad to help. For more information about [numpy boolean array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)

Comment: so that's what my problem is called. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the is the operation you are trying to do.  I suggest using the `np.where` routine for setting values less than 0.25 to zero.  Then you can sum over just the first dimension of the array to get the output array you are looking for.  I reduced the dimensions of the problem for the example.

```
import numpy as np

vals = np.random.random([24, 2, 3])
vals_filtered = np.where(vals < 0.25, 0.0, vals)
out = vals_filtered.sum(axis=0)
print("First sample array has the slice vals[0,:,:]:\n{}\n".format(vals[0, :, :]))
print("First sample array with vals>0.25 set to 0.0:\n{}\n".format(vals_filtered[0, :, :]))
print("Output array is the sum over the first dimension:\n{}\n".format(out))
```

This returns the following output.

```
First sample array has the slice vals[0, :, :]: 
[[ 0.16272567  0.13695067  0.5954866 ]
 [ 0.50367823  0.8519252   0.3000367 ]]

First sample array with vals>0.25 set to 0.0: 
[[ 0.          0.          0.5954866 ]
 [ 0.50367823  0.8519252   0.3000367 ]]

Output array is the sum over the first dimension: 
[[ 11.12707813  12.04175706  11.5812803 ]
 [ 13.73036272   9.3988165   12.41808745]]
```

Is this the calculation you were looking for?  Calling `vals.sum(axis=0)` is a faster way to do the operation.  It is usually better to call numpy's built-in array routines, as opposed to an explicit `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks to you, now I know another new syntax (and new logic) for simple problem like mine. Great information.